# How would you declare a javascript class in an augmented module?

Tags: javascript

Would the following:

```
function ClassName() {}
```

be equal to:

```
var ClassName = function(){}
```

?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
MODULE = (function(x) {

    x.ClassName = function(){}
    // add some functions to ClassName class...
    return x
})(MODULE);
```

Given what I've read elsewhere on how to create a class, I'm not sure if this is correct?

UPDATE:
Ok you can just use object literals as well e.g.

```
var ClassName = {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: The answer in the link you provided would not have helped me. However, should you feel I am wrong, then you are more than welcome to delete this post.

Comment: There are no classes, only Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is valid:

```
var ClassName = function(){}
```

You can give it a try:

```js
var ClassName = function(){}
var a = new ClassName();
document.writeln(typeof a); //object
document.writeln(a instanceof ClassName); //true
```

Comment: I don't know much about this language but im LOVING it thus far. Thank you Theraot.

Answer (score 0):

`function className() {}` and `var className = function(){}` represent the same thing. See the examples below:

```
function Person(name, age){

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
     }

    Person.prototype.howOld =function(){
        console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old")
    }
    var person1 = new Person("John", 29);
    person1.howOld(); //John is 29 years old
```

The above would give you the same output as the below:

```
var Person = function(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
 }

Person.prototype.howOld =function(){
    console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old")
}
var person1 = new Person("John", 29); 
person1.howOld(); //John is 29 years old
```

UPDATE: If you look at the two from a purely functional point of view, you might want to  consider something called hoisting. The above is just to show their similarity from a class/object point of view.

Comment: The two styles differ in timing.  The `function Person() {}` style is hoisted to the top of the current scope so it will be available for us ANYWHERE in the scope.  The `var Person = function() {}` style is only valid AFTER the definition in the current scope.

Comment: Yes, but, I was just interested in stating their similarity when it comes to inheritance. But hoisting can be a factor depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You said "represents the same thing" which is 99% true, but not 100% true (because of the hoisting difference).